# Are hurricane storm surges smaller when the storms strike small islands?

Tags: tropical-cyclone, storms

My understanding of a storm surge is that it is caused by the hurricane "pushing" water towards the land. When a hurricane makes landfall, this water washes up on the short generating a storm surge. From the Wikipedia article, certain geographical features such as shallow water or a funnel-shaped landfall point can exacerbate surges since the water pushed by the storm cannot dissipate (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storm_surge).

Thus, when a hurricane strikes a small island, is the storm surge usually not as much of a problem since the water can dissipate around the island? Are islands thus often less affected by the flooding aspect of hurricanes vs. mainland landfall locations?

Comment: it would depend on the local bathymetry around the small island as well - https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1029/2008GL036953